# Creating a Secured Admin URL - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have created an route which i send to yet-to-be admins to join the system as admin. The route is as simple as `myGames/superadmin/register`. Now, i think this route is easy to guess by someone and sign up. Any intruder can do that and get access as admin to my system. Is there anyway of keeping this route secured?

PS: I am new to laravel please.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you want to have a url that will be impossible to guess, you can generate some random string at https://www.random.org/strings/.

Comment: Other than that, only an admin should be able to place someone else as admin. You could also generate a token that will enable them to create an account. Save this on DB, send to their email, and put it somewhere in a url. Then check if the token is valid and if so let them register.

Comment: @Phiter, is it standard and widely accepted to use random strings for url ?

Comment: The most secure way is not to have a publicly available URL for signing up as admin. Usually admins are assigned manually. Using a random string (usually `md5` of some identificator) is a standard practice for obscuring access to some specific stuff (such as navigation to next items, just by changing the id in the URL), but not really for admin sign ups. I strongly recommend against using a publicly available URL for this.

Comment: @devk, it is acceptable for me to add admins right from the database as well? I guess that is the manual way you are talking about. If that is the case, i think i am okay with your answer

Comment: I mean *how* you're going to do it is up to you to decide depending on how frequently you'll be adding new admins. You could do it directly with database (although you'll have trouble hashing the passwords this way) or make a view that only you (or other admins) can access where you can manages user's roles.

Comment: @devk, well the url i have in the question is not known to anyone just me. It is actually not publicly available but then i am just saying it is easy to guess

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

1- Generate some token (something like 98q4w94qw98d1q98w4e9x) and store it on the database on a table only for storing admin registration tokens.

2- Send your url with this token to your friends, it'd look like this:

```
myGames/superadmin/register/98q4w94qw98d1q98w4e9x
```

3- When the user enters this page, get the token and check if it exists on the database.

4.1 - If the token exists, allow the user to procceed with the registration (then delete the token from the database as it is no longer needed).

4.2 - If the token doesn't exist, either redirect the person to somewhere else or display a message saying "Invalid registration token" or something.

This way, even if someone guesses this url, they won't be able to register because they don't have a token.

This is what your route would look like:

```
Route::get('myGames/superadmin/register/{token?}', function($token = null){
    if (!$token){
        abort(403, "Only users with a token may enter.");
    }
    if(DB::table('admin_tokens')->where('token', $token)->count() === 0){
        abort(403, "It seems like your token is not valid.");
    }
    else{
        return view('admin.register');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but it assumes the author knows who is going to sign up (and in that case I still think manual creating of admins is the better choice most of the time). Also I would add that after step 4.1 you should delete the token from the database.

Comment: He said he has sent it to the "yet-to-be admins". This should work as he knows who are the admins. Thanks for reminding of the token removal!

Comment: If the author does not know who will sign up, he can just allow anyone to register but keep the account as disabled. Then he should have some list and accept registrations there.